# Sentence Construction - The flow of my sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

If I say for example:

**I took a shower, got dressed and had lunch at 1:00 pm**

You guys will think I did these things at all the same time? 
How can I improve my sentence, so it won't be misunderstood ?
What I want to say is:

**First, I took a shower, then I got dressed and after it I  Had lunch at 1:00 pm**

So: Take a shower - 1st event
2- Get dressed - 2ns event
3- Have lunch at 1:00 pm - 3rd action

Should I use past perfect? But how? Feel free to provide me some examples

Comment: ... and then at 1:00pm I had lunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your initial sentence, though personally I'd add the Oxford comma:

> I took a shower, got dressed, and had lunch at 1:00 pm.

As a native English speaker, I'd interpret this as placing 1 pm only with the last action:

- I took a shower before 1 pm.
- Then I got dressed, also before 1 pm.
- Then I had lunch at 1 pm.

If you *did* want to say that you (somehow) did all these things at 1pm, you'd move the 1 pm:

> At 1:00 pm I took a shower, got dressed, and had lunch.

You could also say:

> I took a shower at 1:00 pm, and then got dressed and had lunch.

Comment: after it is wrong in the OP's sentence. It has to be **after that**.

Comment: @Lambie I don't know what you're trying to say.

Comment: [and] after it I had lunch at 1:00 pm. It has to be: and after that. In speech, after it here is not natural sounding...

Comment: @Lambie You're welcome to make your own answer and say that.  I didn't address it because rewording the sentence wasn't necessary anyway.